# Qt release build needs visual studio libraries to work

Tags: qt

I created a Qt program then released it and solved all Qt dependencies using windeployqt.exe. On PCs supporting visual studio the program works fine, but on other PCs the program gives an error saying it needs some visual studio libraries like MSVCP140D.dll can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: That *_D_.dll is not right, that is a debug build of the C/C++ runtime, make sure you run windeployqt with the path to the release build of your application. 
If you already do that, Qt used the same name scheme, so check Qt dlls that were copied for deploy for the extra _d_ at the end, maybe it's a bug in windeployqt that copies one or more debug dll (extra _d_ at the end of filename)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. MS Visual Studio DLL should be on the PC you run it.

> In addition, the archive must contain the following compiler specific
> libraries (assuming Visual Studio 14.0 (2015) or 15.0 (2017) or 16.0
> (2019)):
>
> **Component -> File Name**
>
> The C run-time -> vccorlib140.dll, vcruntime140.dll
>
> The C++ run-time -> msvcp140.dll

[source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html)

Comment: Notice the **D** at the end of `MSVCP140D`. Although all my libraries are compiled using release configuration and code generation is `MT/`